# Importing another py file from a folder in working directory

Tags: python

I want to import a py file from another folder in the working directory. The folder structure is

```
$ ls
a.py  foo/  
$ ls game/
ff.py
```

In `a.py`, I have `from foo.ff import ZZ`, but when I run `a.py`, I get

```
ImportError: No module named foo.ff
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Python 2.x.x - 3.2.x**

To include the file as a package, it must be initiated by an empty `__init__.py` file. inside the folder.

Try making an empty file inside the `foo` directory named `__init__.py` and try again.

Comment: No need for python 3.3+.

Comment: @Marcos thank you, I have edited with python 2.x heading.

Answer (score 1):

The folder structure is unclear inside `foo` there is a folder named `game` and then inside `game` is `ff.py`? Then it should be:

```
from foo.game.ff import ZZ
```